# How does Visual Basic .NET facilitate “disconnected data access”?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

how does Visual Basic .NET facilitate “disconnected data access” and what are the different functions carried out by each ADO.net?
i am really struggling to grasp it!

Comment: The typical answer is `DataSet` and `DataAdapter` are the two primary tools used to facilitate disconnected data-access.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnected data access is primarily achieved by using DataSet and DataAdapter Classes. It is an In-Memory representation of the data in the database table. In layman terms after you fetch data from database to the DataSet using a DataAdapter you could access the data which is in memory without connecting to the database again. Please find below a link with a simple good explanation of the both.

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson05

Please mark it as answer if you find this useful.